# Конструкция decltype(auto)

Tags: c++, c++14

Зачем нужна конструкция `decltype(auto)` при возврате из функции, если можно писать `auto`?

Comment: Думаю, для совместимости. Если ваш компилятор не поддерживает decltype-и, то достаточно написать #define decltype(a), а так вам прийдётся подменять auto и другие виды подтипов.

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24109737/3240681

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`auto` это "усохший" (decayed) тип выражения, т.е. теряются ссылки и происходит копирование:

```
string& f();

auto x = f();  // тип x - string, ссылка потерялась, строка скопировалась

auto g() { return f(); }  // возвращается string
// аналог в С++11: auto g() -> decay<decltype(f())>::type;
```

`decltype(expr)` - это фактический тип выражения, без усыханий.
`decltype(auto)` - это удобный синтаксис, который позволяет не писать выражение внутри `decltype`.

```
decltype(auto) y = f();  // тип y - string&
// аналог в С++11: decltype(f()) y = f();

decltype(auto) h() { return f(); }  // возвращается string&
// аналог в С++11: auto h() -> decltype(f());
```

Другими словами, `decltype(auto)` это удобная замена `decltype(expr)`,
а `auto` это короткий синтаксис для `std::decay<decltype(auto)>::type`.

Answer (score 5):

**auto**

В С++11 ключевое слово auto лишено своего первоначального смысла в качестве спецификатора класса хранения и теперь применяется для реализации автоматического выведения типа при условии, что задан явный инициализатор. Компилятор устанавливает тип переменной в тип инициализирующего значения:

```
auto maton = 112;       // maton получает тип int 
auto pt    = &maton;    // pt получает тип int * 
double fm(double, int); 
auto pf    = fm;        // pf получает тип double (*) (double, int)
```

Ключевое слово auto может также упростить объявления шаблонов. Например, если іl является объектом типа `std::initializer_list<double>`, следующий код

```
for (std::initializer_list<double>::iterator p = il.begin(); 
            p !=il.end(); p++)
```

можно заменить таким:

```
for (auto p = il.begin(); p != il.end(); p++)
```

**decltype**

Ключевое слово decltype создает переменную типа, который указан выражением. Приведенный ниже оператор означает "назначить у тот же самый тип, что х", где х представляет собой выражение:

```
decltype(х) у;
```

Вот еще пара примеров:

```
double x; 
int n; 
decltype(x*n) q;  // q получает тот же тип, что и х*n, т.е. double 
decltype(&x) pd;  // pd получает тот же тип, что и &х, т.е. double *
```

Это особенно полезно в определениях шаблонов, когда тип может быть не  определен вплоть до создания специфического экземпляра:

```
template<typename Т, typename U) 
void ef (T t, U u) 
{ 
    decltype(T*U) tu; 
    ...
}
```

**Хвостовой возвращаемый тип**

В С++11 появился новый синтаксис для объявления функций, при котором возвращаемый тип указывается после имени функции и списка параметров, а не перед ними:

```
double f1(double, int);         // традиционный синтаксис 
auto f2(double, int) -> double; // новый синтаксис, // возвращаемым типом является double
```

Новый синтаксис может выглядеть менее читабельным, чем традиционные  объявления функций, однако он делает возможным использование `decltype` для указания возвращаемых типов шаблонных функций:

```
template<typename Т, typename U) 
auto eff (T t, U u) -> decltype (T*U) 
{ 
}
```

Иллюстрируемая здесь проблема состоит в том, что когда компилятор читает  список параметров ef f, Т и U не находятся в области видимости, поэтому любое использование `decltype` должно находиться после этого списка параметров. Новый  синтаксис делает это возможным.

Comment: Да, я уже понял. Такой синтаксис вишу впервые. Буду пользоваться - удобно. Спасибо!