# В чём разница между decltype(auto) и auto&&?

Tags: c++, c++14

В чём разница между `decltype(auto)` и `auto&&`?

Понятно, что типы вычисляются по разным механизмам, но есть ли разница в конечном результате?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Раз типы вычисляются по разным механизмам, то и разница в конечном результате присутствует, иначе зачем тогда было бы два способа (хотя в С++ куча мест где без причин есть несколько способов сделать одно и то же)?

```
#include <type_traits>

class foo {};
foo bar() { return foo{}; }

decltype(auto) var1{bar()};
auto && var2{bar()};
static_assert(::std::is_same_v<decltype(var1), class foo>);
static_assert(::std::is_same_v<decltype(var2), class foo &&>);
```

Comment: а при инициализации переменной есть разница?

Comment: @tibo В этом примере как раз показывается разница при инициализации переменных...

Comment: Тут же тип возвращаемого значения функции вычисляется. А я имею в виду, есть ли разница между `decltype(auto) x = ... ;` и `auto&& x = ...;` ?

Comment: @tibo Нет, типа возвращаемого значения функции тут не вычисляется, тут показывается как раз разница между `decltype(auto) x = ... ;` и `auto&& x = ...;`

Comment: Ааа, понял. Думал там круглые скобки :)

Comment: Интересно, что в VC++ `decltype(auto) var1{bar()};` не компилируется, приходится писать `decltype(auto) var1 = bar();`

Comment: @Harry Похоже на баг

Comment: У вас код c++17 :)

Answer (score 1):

Безусловно разница есть, но в некоторых случаях могут быть и одинаковые результаты. Ничего удивительного в том, что разные подходы могут при некотором стечении обстоятельств давать одинаковые результаты быть не должно. [Пример](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gdu64KzyWzhTWTdE):

```
#include <type_traits>

int& f() 
{
    static int i = 42;
    return i;
}

int g() { return 42; }

int main()
{
    auto&& v1 = f();
    decltype(auto) v2 = f();

    auto&& v3 = g();
    decltype(auto) v4 = g();    

    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(v1), int&>::value);
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(v2), int&>::value);

    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(v3), int&&>::value);
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(v4), int>::value);
}
```

Для переменной, используемой в качестве результата `f()` и `auto&&` и `decltype(auto)` дадут одинаковые типы - `int&`. С функцией `g()` уже будут другие результаты - `int&&` и `int` соответственно.

`decltype(auto)` даёт тип объявления сущности, т.е. в случае функций объявленный тип результата: `int&` для `f()`, и `int` для `g()`. Подробнее можно посмотреть [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/563318/176217).

В свою очередь вывод для `auto&&` будет работать по схеме вывода типа параметра в шаблоне следующего вида:

```
template <class T>
void t(T&& a); // T вместо auto
```

Если [вызвать](https://wandbox.org/permlink/UGapFUrwYblNKWfN) `t(f())` то тип `a` будет выведен как `int&`, а для `t(g())` получится `int&&`.

Answer (score -1):

Выражение вида `auto&& foo = make_foo(params);` будет корректно в большинстве случаев, за исключением некоторых прокси-объектов. Если `make_foo` возвращает тип `bar`, `foo` будет иметь тип `bar&&`, при этом время жизни возвращаемого значения будет расширено до времени жизни `foo`. Т.е. это корректно, как и в таком случае:

```
std::string&& str = std::string("foo");
std::string str2 = std::move(str);
```

Если `make_foo` возвращает `bar&`,  `const bar&` или `const bar&`, `foo` будет иметь соответствующий тип. Это полезно, например, при работе с кортежами:

```
std::tuple<bar&, const bar&, bar&&> t = ...;
auto&& r1 = std::get<0>(t); // bar&
auto&& r2 = std::get<1>(t); // const bar&
auto&& r3 = std::get<2>(t); // bar&&
```

В случае `decltype(auto)` это перестаёт работать. В выражении `decltype(auto) foo = make_foo(params);`, если `make_foo` возвращает `bar`, `foo` будет иметь тип `bar`, т.е. значение будет сразу перемещено или будет применена оптимизация возвращаемого значения, что не всегда желательно.
Пример:

```
auto&& foo= makeBar(); // Bar&&

// перемещение или инициализация на месте, Эквивалентно vector.emplace_back(makeBar())
vector.emplace_back(foo);
```

Или

```
decltype(auto) baz = makeBar(); // Перемещение или инициализация на месте
vector.emplace_back(baz); // Копирование
```

Comment: *Если `make_foo` возвращает `bar&&`, `foo` будет иметь тип `bar&`* - почему не `bar&&`? *значение будет сразу перемещено или будет применена оптимизация возвращаемого значения, что не всегда желательно* - почему не всегда желательно?

Comment: Почему вы мне не отвечаете? 

Comment: @dIm0n , я не так часто сюда захожу. На счет `bar&&`->`bar&` я, видимо, ошибся. У `bar->bar`, проблема в перемещении, оптимизация возвращаемого значения - это оптимальный частный случай. В случае с auto вы можете написать `auto&& foo= make(); vector.emplace_back(foo);` (время жизни foo проливается, как и в случае с const ref&). При этом будет ровно одно перемещение. Если foo имеет тип Bar, то будет одно перемещение и одно копирование, или, если дописать std::move(), два перемещения.

Comment: Честно говоря, не понял, как вторая часть комментария относится к моему комментарию. А вот по первой части понял, что `bar&&` -> `bar&` стоит исправить в ответе, а если *оптимизация возвращаемого значения - это оптимальный частный случай*, то значит эта оптимизация желательна, разве нет?

Comment: @dIm0n , оптимизация возвращаемого значения лучше перемещения, но все еще хуже отсутствия действий. Если мы работаем со ссылками, мы часто хотим передать саму ссылку, а не создавать объект лишний раз. Смотрите обновленный пример.

Comment: *оптимизация возвращаемого значения лучше перемещения, но все еще хуже отсутствия действий* - разве оптимизация возвращаемого значения не есть конструирование объекта на месте? То есть это самая лучшая из возможных ситуаций, не конструировать вообще невозможно же :) А в примере у вас первом тоже копирование, а не *перемещение или инициализация на месте*

Comment: @dim0n , оптимизация возвращаемого значения позволяет сконструировать объект на месте, вопрос только, на каком. В первом случае конструирование может быть осуществлено сразу в массиве, во втором - конструирование на стеке, затем копирование/перемещение в массив. Причем оптимизация срабатывает не всегда, в худшем случае вместо одного перемещения получим два, или вообще перемещение и копирование, если забудем вызвать move.

Comment: Ещё раз повторяю, в первом случае в новом примере у вас копирование `foo` тоже, если `vector` - это `std::vector<Bar>`. Мы говорили про оптимизацию возвращаемого значения, а тут откуда-то вектор появился с вызовом функций