# Неявное преобразование std::string -> std::string_view

Tags: c++

```
// Вектор заполняется всякой фигней:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string_view>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<string> s{"aaa", "bbb", "aaa", "aaa"};
    vector<string_view> vs(4);
    transform(s.begin(), s.end(),
              vs.begin(),
              [](auto& data) {return data;});

    for (auto item: vs) {
        cout << item.data() << " ";     // Вывод: ��o ��o ��o ��o
    }
    cout << endl;

    for (auto item: vs) {
        cout << item << " ";    // Вывод: �@" �@" �@" �@"
    }
    cout << endl;
}

// А так все нормально
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string_view>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<string> s{"aaa", "bbb", "aaa", "aaa"};
    vector<string_view> vs(4);
    transform(s.begin(), s.end(),
              vs.begin(),
              [](auto& data) -> string_view {return data;});

    for (auto item: vs) {
        cout << item.data() << " ";     // Вывод: aaa bbb aaa aaa
    }
    cout << endl;

    for (auto item: vs) {
        cout << item << " ";    // Вывод: aaa bbb aaa aaa
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Почему в первом случае не происходит неявного преобразования из string в string_view? Точнее, оно скорее всего происходит, но для какого-то временного значения, область видимости которого - функция std::transfor. Объясните пожалуйста, почему так происходит?

Я понимаю, что функция std::transform возвращает строку - копию элемента исходного вектора, поэтому представление string_view получает указатель на данные, область видимости которых ограничена функцией std::transform. Все верно? Получается, без явного каста здесь никак не обойтись? Указать функции std::transform возвращать ссылку на элемент исходной последовательности невозможно?

Comment: В первом случае лямбда возвращает копию строки (т.к. тип возвращаемого из лямбды значения не указан, то компилятор его вывел сам как `std::string`). И эта копия служит инициализатором для `string_view` объекта. На очередной итерации цикла в недрах `std::transform` эта копия строки уничтожается, следовательно `string_view` инвалидируется. Во втором случае тип возвращаемого лямбдой выражения указан явно — `std::string_view`, т.е. из лямбды возвращается корректно инициализированный `std::string_view`. Он привязан не к копии строки, а непосредственно к строке из вектора `s`.

Comment: `Я понимаю, что функция std::transform возвращает строку`. Функция `std::transform` возвращает итератор. Вероятно здесь подразумевалась лямбда? `Указать функции std::transform возвращать ссылку на элемент исходной последовательности невозможно?` Вы же смогли указать _лямбде_ возвращать `std::string_view`... Можно указать и ссылку. В данном конкретном случае так: `-> std::string&`, или так: `-> auto&`, или даже [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/563318): `-> decltype(auto)`.

Comment: @wololo, супер, спасибо! А decltype(auto) ссылку разве вернет?

Comment: @wololo, правильно ли я понимаю, что decltype(auto) вернет тот же тип, что и у аргумента лямбды, да? А в чем тогда смысл его использования в данном случае? Почему не auto& например?

Comment: @Давид, по второму вопросу, auto& - в обычном виде теряет ссылку и при его использовании произойдет копирование. decltype(auto) - гарантирует точное выполнение с тем типом, который вы задали

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/563318/Конструкция-decltypeauto?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @АлександрКозлов *"auto& - в обычном виде теряет ссылку"* ?? Можно пример?

Comment: @АлександрКозлов проще понимать `auto` как шаблонный параметр, т.е. `auto&` работает по таким же правилам, что и `void foo(T&)`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, в принципе я могу это как часть вопроса засчитать к вопросу Давида, поэтому считаю что могу оставить ответ на ваш подвопрос тут снизу(с примерами). Давид тоже этим интересовался, поэтому без проблем.

Comment: @АлександрКозлов Где в вашем ответе `auto &`? Я вижу только `auto`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, да я неправ, потому что опечатался - думал, что вопрос про то почему: когда мы вбиваем auto - он не берет ссылку/указатель

Answer (score 0):

Вот здесь auto не прикрепился к ссылке:

```
 #include <iostream>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    int &returner(int &some_number){
        return some_number; }
    
    int main() {
        int x = 10;
        auto lets_show_it = returner(x);
        cout<<endl<<endl;
        cout<<"OUR X NUMBER "<<x<<" "<<&x<<endl;
        cout<<"LETS SHOT IT "<<lets_show_it<<" "<<&lets_show_it<<endl;
        cout<<endl<<endl;
        lets_show_it = 15;
        cout<<"OUR X NUMBER "<<x<<" "<<&x<<endl;
        cout<<"LETS SHOT IT 2 "<<lets_show_it<<" "<<&lets_show_it<<endl;
 }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот здесь auto прикрепился к ссылке:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int &returner(int &some_number){
    return some_number;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 10;
    decltype(auto) lets_show_it = returner(x);
    cout<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"OUR X NUMBER "<<x<<" "<<&x<<endl;
    cout<<"LETS SHOT IT "<<lets_show_it<<" "<<&lets_show_it<<endl;
    cout<<endl<<endl;
    lets_show_it = 15;
    cout<<"OUR X NUMBER "<<x<<" "<<&x<<endl;
    cout<<"LETS SHOT IT 2 "<<lets_show_it<<" "<<&lets_show_it<<endl;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запись decltype(auto) - компилятор нативно поймет, что нужно int&